# How do I subscribe to Google monthly timeline activity emails

Tags: google-maps

Earlier I used to get monthly/annual E-Mails of place I traveled and stats about them. But they have stopped since March now.

I went to https://www.google.com/maps/timeline?pb -> Settings -> Timeline emails. It's already enabled from here. What I am missing then?

Answer (score 1):

I've not been getting them since March either (thinking - maybe I got one).

It's likely that Google decided that it would be better for worldwide morale if we didn't get reminders that we're not travelling at the moment like we used to due to Covid-19 restrictions.  But only Google really knows.

Comment: It's so strange I finally got this E-Mail 2 days ago. I guess disabling/enabling the setting might have fixed it.